# Java Date() giving the wrong date

Tags: java, date

I've got a simple method that should get the current date, put it into a certain format and then return it as a String. Up to this point it's been fine (last tried it on about 31st Jan) but for some reason when I tried it today it returns the String "2013-02-43".

Now obviously there aren't 43 days in February and I have no idea why it's returning this. I've searched everywhere I can for a solution but none of them seem to fit the specific problem I am having. Here is the code:

```
public String getDate(){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
    Date date = new Date();

    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Just for the record I've tried using Calendar.getInstance() etc. with the same result. Interestingly when I try

```
get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

it comes back with 12, so somewhere the numbers are right but something's going wrong in between.

Thanks

Comment: "d" Not "D" specifies "Day in month", "M" not "m" specifies "Month in year". I feel a little bit ashamed to get reputation from this kind of questions.

Comment: For the record, when *two* different APIs aren't producing the results you suspect it's unlikely that the problem resides in the APIs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`DD` means Day of Year, while `dd` means Day of Month. Also, `Y` means Week Year, while `y` means Year. You want `yyyy-MM-dd` (case-sensitive).

```
public String getDate(){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();

    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was dumb of me, my bad. Thanks so much!

Comment: Shouldn't `YYYY` be also replaced with `yyyy`?

Answer (score 4):

Capital D in a `DateFormat` is date in year.  You want date in month:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:  "yyyy-MM-dd"

Case sensitivity matters.  "DD" is the day in the year.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .toString()
```

> 2016-12-24

## Details

The [accepted Answer by Cashwell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836061/642706) is correct: The formatting pattern codes are incorrect, case-sensitive.

## Using java.time

The more modern way to do this is with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### Strings

Your desired output happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard text formats for date-time values. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern at all!

```
String output = today.toString() ;
```

> 2016-12-24

By the way, while there is no need to do so in this case, if you were to create a formatting pattern it would look like this code example. The codes are similar to those of `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly the same, so study the class doc carefully.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd" );
String output = today.format( f );
```

Usually best to also specify a `Locale` as a habit, but not necessary in this particular case.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use format "yyyy-MM-dd" with lower case d. Capital D is the format for day in year. You can find an overview of date patterns [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Read the [javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). `Y` doesn't exist, and `D` is the day in year. You want `yyyy-MM-dd` as your pattern.

Comment: Y was added in Java 7 as place holder for "week-year".

Answer (score 0):

Your format string should be `"YYYY-MM-dd"` rather than `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.

`DD` is "Day in year", while `dd` is "Day in month".

Check out the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: *And* the "yyyy" should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dateformat should be in lower case

`DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

That returns 2013-02-12

Else it returns the day of the year.

Please refer to [SimpleDateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) page for the entire list of accepted format patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

It should be `dd` and not `DD`.