# Can't get date from DateChooserCombo

Tags: java, swing, date, compiler-errors, jdatechooser

I'm trying to get the date from `DateChooserCombo` as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
String date = sdf.format(dateChooser.getDate());
```

But the method `getDate()` gives me error (illegal forward reference). I have also tried with `getSelectedDate()` but it's the same. What can I do?

Anyway I'm using Apache Netbeans 12.1 and the date picker should be this one:
https://github.com/vadimig/jdatechooser

Thanks.

Comment: *"What can I do?"* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It should only take 20-30 lines of code to reproduce the compiler error.

Comment: Note that the format string `YYYY-MM-DD` is most likely wrong. Read the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - you probably need `yyyy-MM-dd`. Case is important, when you use a different case it means a different thing. (This is however not the cause of the error you are asking about).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You may also want to go looking for a date picker that support java.time if the one  you are using now doesn’t.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Date() giving the wrong date \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836004/java-date-giving-the-wrong-date)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the `JDateChooser` code from the link you provided in your question. There is **no** `getDate()` method in class `datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo`. There is a `getSelectedDate()` method which returns an instance of class [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Also, according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for class `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD` is a valid pattern but I don't think it's the pattern that you want. `D` means day in year which means that 27<sup>th</sup> February is the 58<sup>th</sup> day of the year. You probably want `d`. Similarly, `Y` means [`Week year`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691582/how-does-java-week-year-really-work) whereas you probably wanted `y`.

So, in order to get a string representation of the date that the user selected from the `DateChooserCombo`, you probably want the following code.

```java
DateChooserCombo dcc = new DateChooserCombo(); // or however you create and configure it
Calendar cal = dcc.getSelectedDate();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

By the way, it appears that `JDateChooser` development stopped seven years ago. Perhaps consider using [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) which has a [DatePicker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) component which works with Java's [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).