# Why it shows errors at swing components

Tags: java, swing, date, simpledateformat, jdatechooser

I am new to `JFrame`. I just started learning about creating a Java project. I created an input field as a date and inserted a `DateChooseCombo`. I have 2 problems.

1. When I run the application dates in the calendar are invisible but, it shows the date which is selected in the box.
2. When I submit the form it gives an error as `"Cannot format given Object as a Date"`

The code for the date is as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String addDate = dateFormat.format(txt_AddDate.getSelectedDate());
ps.setString(3 ,addDate);
```

The date format used is `04/30/2021`.

Can anyone help me to solve these two problems?

Comment: If you post a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE and test, then you're more likely to get help.  Without seeing the code, we can't tell what you did.

Comment: The IDE is irrelevant to the problem (unless the code works OK in another IDE). Don't tag it or mention it in the title.

Comment: If the date format is is 04/30/21, why are you specifying format MM/dd/yyyy, which is for 04/30/2021?

Comment: Two recommendations: (1) Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Date pickers exist that support `LocalDate` *and* Swing. (2) Don’t pass the selected date as a string to your prepared statement. Pass a `LocalDate`. See [Insert & fetch …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `getSelectedDate()`, in class `datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo`, returns a [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Method [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-), in class `java.text.DateFormat` (which is superclass of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and hence inherited by `SimpleDateformat`) requires a parameter of type [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). A `Calendar` is **not** a `Date` and that's why you are getting the error. Java cannot convert a `Calendar` to a `Date`.

However, class `Calendar` has method [getTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) which returns a `Date`.
So you need to change the second line of the code, that you posted in your question, to the following.

```java
String addDate = dateFormat.format(txt_AddDate.getSelectedDate().getTime());
```

You can also refer to the following question (and answer) :
[Can't get date from DateChooserCombo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387658/cant-get-date-from-datechoosercombo)